# Drag coefficient for tilted plane

Tags: drag, aerodynamics

I'm trying to calculate the drag force for a thin rectangular plate with dimensions $L×d$, like shown in the image below, with air flow (approximately) perpendicular to the plane defined by the plate. This is what's shown below. What I want to do now though is calculate the drag coefficient when the direction of air flow is say 15 degrees off from perpendicular (in either or both of the directions). Obviously the surface projected onto a plane perpendicular to air flow would decrease, but I also imagine the drag coefficient would decrease, so I'm wondering by how much.

[image]

Comment: How thin is rectangular plate?

Comment: @AlexTrounev can we just assume trivially thin or will it make a big difference? Probably <5% of L or d. If it's confusing, the thinness is not referring to the L or d dimension, but instead the third dimension.

Comment: There is a big difference for zero or 5% of L in a case of  $15^o$ from normal.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but why?

Comment: It depends on flow around.

Comment: Okay L is 250mm, d is 50mm, thickness is 3mm

Comment: It would be a whole different problem. You couldn't use any of the information in the image.

Answer (score 0):

if you tild by an angle  the flow still encounters a rectangle, but you have a different L or d  or both depending in which direction you told tho you find the new Cd in your table.

Comment: My intuition says that it doesn't work like that. Wouldn't that mean that a shape with two angled planes like this: < would have the same drag coefficient as a flat plane like this: l ? (assuming same cross-sectional area perpendicular to air flow)

Comment: The tilt angle will change the frontal area: $Lcos(\theta) dcos(\phi)$ and the L/D ratio: $\frac {Lcos(\theta)}{d cos(\phi)}$